# Настройка nginx, apaсhe2 и php5.4 для Debian

Tags: nginx, debian, apache2

После apache2 необходимо перейти на связку nginx+apache2. В целях безопасности и в целях производительности.

После изучения документации удалось сделать:

1. В конфиге apache2 настроить его на прослушку 81-го порта.
2. В конфиге nginx настроить его на 80 порт.

Теперь при переходе на сайт вижу приветственное окно Nginx, но запустить сайт не удалось.

Получилось даже увидеть установочную страницу Prestashop (дистрибутив предварительно загрузил) и пройти все шаги, но после успешной установки вижу только белую страницу.

Как это можно правильно настроить или подробнее прочитать об этом?

---

Сделал все как Вы сказали, но приветственное окно nginx не пропало.
Полностью развернутый сайт находится в директории /var/www/html, там же находился и приветственный файл nginx. 
Я его удалил и теперь "403 Forbidden nginx/1.6.2".
Вот конфиг:

```
    server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name html; #ВАШ_ДОМЕН

    # Перенаправление на back-end
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 180;
    }

    # Статическиое наполнение отдает сам nginx
    # back-end этим заниматься не должен
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt)$ {
        root /var/www/html; #ПУТЬ_ДО_КОРНЕВОГО_КАТАЛОГА_САЙТА
    }
}
```

---

Разворачиваю локально, но доступ нужен удаленно.
Вот адрес - http://sgus.ddns.net:61840/
Порт 61840 проброшен на 80-й.

Читает только файлы с расширением .html

Comment: Просьба, не забывайте отмечать ответ ;)

Comment: Разворачиваете локально, или на удалённом VPS?

Comment: Вопрос по-прежнему не решен.

Comment: Сергей, вы можете мне ответить на комментарий? Вы разворачиваете локально или на удалённом VPS?

Comment: Разворачиваю локально, но доступ нужен удаленно. Вот адрес - http://sgus.ddns.net:61840/ Порт 61840 проброшен на 80-й. У меня не было возможности отвечать на комментарии, поэтому ответ размещал посредством редактирования своего вопроса...

Comment: cat /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: 2017/10/06 14:02:56 [error] 3915#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden

Comment: Попробуйте присвоить директории `/var/www` и поддиректории права 0775 и группу www-data. `sudo chmod -R 0775 /var/www` и `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www`, потом перезагрузить nginx

Comment: Безрезультатно.

Comment: "Читает только файлы с расширением .html" ну понятное дело что только html, потому что Nginx настроен на проксирование запросов, а не на обработку. А Apache вы настроили, чтобы он у вас корректно обрабатывал .php файлы? Apache без nginx у вас способен .php файл обработать? P.S. К слову Nginx 1.6 устарел, сейчас актуальна версия 1.11. PHP 5.4 так же устарел. Используйте минимум 5.6, а лучше 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую!
Nginx - отдаёт статику.
Apache - динамику.

То что вы видите страницу приветствия Nginx вполне логично,
т.к. вы не настроили проксирование запросов от Nginx в Apache

Допустим что имя вашего сайте my-site.ru

В директории `/etc/nginx/sites-available` создайте файл `my-site.conf`
Это файл настройки для вашего будущего сайта. Внутрь поместите следующий код:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name my-site.ru; #ВАШ_ДОМЕН

    # Перенаправление на back-end
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 180;
    }

    # Статическиое наполнение отдает сам nginx
    # back-end этим заниматься не должен
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt)$ {
        root /var/www/папка_проекта; #ПУТЬ_ДО_КОРНЕВОГО_КАТАЛОГА_САЙТА
    }
}
```

После этого нужно создать символьную ссылку в папку `sites-enabled`
Выполнив команду: 
`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my-site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site.conf`

Не забудьте проверить, файл `nginx.conf`, который находится в `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` на наличие в конце команды `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

После всего вышеописанного, выполните команду: `sudo service nginx restart`,
если всё сделано верно, то nginx перезапустится и всё будет ок. :)

**P.S.** Вы можете пропустить манипуляции с символьными ссылками, если сразу создадите файл `my-site.conf`, в директории `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

**P.P.S.** От себя добавлю, если проект новый, то рекомендую смотреть в сторону PHP7 и PHP7-FPM за место Apache, т.к. он работает гораздо быстрее. Да и вообще в сторону PHP-FPM даже если PHP7 по какой-либо причине не подходит.

Comment: Автор вопроса вам ответил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/726603/181472